# ASP.NET Web API 2 Url-based Versioning

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I've been trying to configure Url-based versioning in Web API 2.0 but so far it doesn't work.

***WebApiConfig***

```
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new ostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

***Controller***

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/customers")]
[ValidateRequestModel]
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
  ....
}
```

It works well without v1 but when I add v1 to the route prefix as mentioned above, IIS gives me 403 forbidden error (IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 403.18 - Forbidden). Can you help to suggest what went wrong?

**Updated:** 
[image]
[image]

```
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CustomerCreateResponseMessage))]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateFolder([FromBody] CustomerCreateRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<CustomerCreateResponseMessage>(HttpStatusCode.Created, new CustomerCreateResponseMessage { Message = "OK!"  });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the action and url you call that is giving the 403 status code

Comment: at first glance the `HostAuthenticationFilter` seems to be the cause but cannot say for sure without more details in the question

Comment: @Nkosi ... I've just added the screen-shots.

Comment: You haven't included the code for the action that is supposed to be called.

Comment: Ok given that I don't have enough information about the action being called, here is my shot in the dark. Put an [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the action you are trying to hit. Given that the path matches the route prefix I'd guess its the root action which would be the action that you have the [Route("")] attribute.

Comment: @Nkosi .. So far I am using Postman to test my API. There is no client code.

Comment: not client side code. the code in the controller.

Comment: @Nkosi ... I've just added the code. It is very simple- just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`HostAuthenticationFilter` in your configuration indicates that requests need to be authenticated/authorized to access your web api.

Either comment out the filter so you can test it in postman without having to authenticate requests

```
//config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

**Or** allow the controller to be able serve anonymous requests by using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the action.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/customers")]
[ValidateRequestModel]
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{        
    [AllowAnonymous] // <--This will allow you to test unauthenticated requests
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CustomerCreateResponseMessage))]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateFolder([FromBody] CustomerCreateRequestMessage request) {...}
}
```

Comment: Let me try that out.

Comment: Where are you hosting the web api, or are just running it in visual studio?

Comment: IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: take a look at your web.config file and see if you've configured it properly

Comment: You said it works with out the route prefix. what url does it work with

Comment: Sorry I was away. "api/customers" it works but "api/v1/customers" it doesn't. It's a bit wired.

Answer (score 0):

What you see (403.18) it's just a masking of the real error and it happens because the IIS tries to load a resource (custom error page, maybe?) which is not under the scope of the application pool of you current "projectabc", but somewhere else. It's clearly marked in the Request URL property of the error page: http://localhost:80/api.php?name=folders (which is definitively not a web api stuff!).

Fix this error the see the real error page and maybe get some more details (probably the problem is you're not sending the right authentication headers to the API, as @Nkosi pointed out).

Check this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2006/09/01/403-18-the-specific-request-cannot-be-executed-from-current-application-pool/) for a specific description of the 403.18 error in a similar case.

Comment: I saw the PHP path but thought that had something to do with postman as I have no experience with that tool.